# Reverse for 'user' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['project/users/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/$']

Tags: python, html, django

NoReverseMatch at /project/users/1/stories/1/

Reverse for 'user' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['project/users/(?P[0-9]+)/$']

Does anyone have any idea why I face this error when I press "python manage.py runserver"? It used to work just fine and now it just doesn't. I've seen that the problem might be with user_id or user.id, but I can't really see it! Here is my code:

**project/views.py**

```
def story(request, user_id, story_id):

if story_id is not None:
    story = get_object_or_404(Story, pk=story_id)
else:
    story = Story()
    story.user_id = user_id

if request.method == 'POST':
    story.title = request.POST['title']
    story.story = request.POST['story']
    story.date = timezone.now()
    story.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('project:story', args=(user_id,)))
else:
    context = {
        'user_id': user_id,
        'story_id': story_id,
        'title': story.title,
        'story': story.story,
        'likes': story.likes,
        'comments': story.comments
    }
return render(request, 'project/story.html', context)
```

**project/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name='index'),
path('register/<int:user_id>/', views.register, name='register'),
path('login/<int:user_id>/', views.login, name='login'),
path('users/<int:user_id>/', views.user, name='user'),
path('users/<int:user_id>/stories/<int:story_id>/', views.story, name='story'),
]
```

**project/templates/project/story.html**

```
{% extends "project/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

{% if story_id %}
    <div class="post-preview">
        <h2 class="post-title"> {{ story.title }}</h2>
        <p class="post-subtitle">
            {{ story.story }}
        </p>
        <p class="post-meta">Posted by
            <a href="{% url 'project:user' story.author.id %}">{{ story.author.username }}</a>
            on {{ story.date }}
            <i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"> {{ story.likes }}</i>
            <i class="fas fa-comment"> {{ story.comments }}</i>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="post-preview">
        <h2> Comments </h2>
        {% for com in latest_comments %}
            <div class="post-preview">
                <p class="post-subtitle"> {{ comment.com }}</p>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="post-preview">
        <form action="{% url 'project:story' user.id story.id %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="text">Comment</label>
                <textarea id="text" name="text"
                          class="form-control" placeholder="Comment" rows="4">{{ comment.com }}
                </textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
{% else %}
    {% if request.story.author.id == user.id %}
        <form action="{% url 'project:story' user.id story.id %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title">Title</label>
                <input type="text" id="title" name="title"
                       class="form-control" placeholder="Title" value="{{ story.title }}"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="text">Story</label>
                <textarea id="text" name="text"
                          class="form-control" placeholder="Story" rows="10">{{ story.story }}
                </textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: `story` is here not a `Story` object, but the text (string), hence the `story.author.id` in `{% url ... %}` does *not* exists, and fallsback on the empty string.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Oh alright, and what do you suggest that I do? Should I change the name of 'def story' so that it doesn't "shadow" the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `context` we see:

```
context = {
    'user_id': user_id,
    'story_id': story_id,
    'title': story.title,
    'story': story.story,
    'likes': story.likes,
    'comments': story.comments
}
```

so the `story` variable does *not* contain a `Story` object, it contains its `story` attribute (probably, based on the rest of the view, a `str`ing).

Now in your template you write:

```
{% url 'project:user' story.author.id %}
```

but since `story` is a `str`ing, it has no `.author` attribute, so this will get evaluated to the `string_if_invalid` which is, unless you specified otherwise, the empty string `''`.

You thus need to pass the story itself in your context to:

```
context = {
    'user_id': user_id,
    'story_id': story_id,
    'title': story.title,
    'story': story,
    'likes': story.likes,
    'comments': story.comments
}
```

Comment: thanks a ton, it worked! Now I face this problem in user.html though.... `<a href="{% url 'project:story' story.id %}">{{ story.title }}</a>`It says story_id is missing.

Comment: Also, I get the same error with the story object. NoReverseMatch at /project/users/1/
Reverse for 'story' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['project/users/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/stories/(?P<story_id>[0-9]+)/$']

Comment: @Despina: I think this is probably in another template. But the idea is probably the same, do you pass the `Story` object, or one of its attributes? It might be better to rename the `story` attribute as well, since now it creates a lot of confusion.